# In C# a method for turning something like C:\mydir\another\again\..\..\ into C:\mydir

Tags: c#

Is there a C# function to translate ..\s in a path so you can get the final path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Path.GetFullPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) should do it.

Answer (score 2):

[`System.IO.Path.GetFullPath()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath.aspx) will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

So you just wanna get the first folder and drop the rest? What about using a regex or string.substring?

As for the regex this one would get it:

\w:\\w+

and for the string substring

somthing like

newPath = path.Substring(4,path.IndexOf("\")-4);

Comment: No, he wants to resolve all `.` and `..` segments. As another example, `C:\foo\bar\baz\..\quux\..\.` would yield `C:\foo\bar`

Comment: I want to translate anything with ..\  in the path to their directory.  eg  C:\blah\..\another\maybe\..\actually\this\..\that..\..\

Comment: oh, well I guess then forget my answer :/ I didnt understand from the question title